# How can I achieve SQL groupby and where in PowerBI?

Tags: group-by, powerbi, slice, dax, aggregation

```
SELECT COUNT([Table].[CustomerID]), AVERAGE([Table].[Values])
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY [Table].[Country]
Where Max([Table].[Date]) < PowerBI_Max_Date_Slicer and Min([Table].[Date]) > PowerBI_Min_Date_Slicer
```

I would like to apply time slicing first then do the groupby in PowerBI with filtered data.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Edit Queries > Home > Group By` and group your table like you need it with the `Max()`, `Min()`, `Count()` and `Average()` aggregation. Now you can filter the grouped table after your slicer and show the corresponding values.

Comment: Thank you, while I want to pass the slicer range parameter before the group by. The aggregation function only applies on the filtered table, otherwise it will aggregate all values instead of acting on the filtered table I have applied the slicer on.

Comment: Also, it is possible to achieve using DAX only?

Comment: Yes should be possibe. I am also not sure how to do it but I can give you some help. You can get your sliver value with `SELECTEDVALUE(YourSlicer)`. A combination from `GROUPBY()`, `CALCULATE()` and `SUM()` could give you the aggregated value.

Comment: Thank you. How can I pass the range value? I found out I can just simply use max() and min() on top of slicer column to get the selected value, but then when I tried to use DATESBETWEEN([Table].[Date], min, max) it comes out with The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value. error